# Yahoo Pipes is removing 2 non-standard elements from output RSS feed

Tags: xml, rss, yahoo-pipes

I need to keep some non-standard elements received by my Yahoo Pipe but I find they are being stripped when I run my pipe and view it as RSS.

http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.edit?_id=5ff9163c29a409001a28ad8ae4b510d3

Specifically, in this pipe I am receiving 'language' and 'copyright' element data within each item. The content for both of these are being removed when the output RSS is viewed (xml is visible in Chrome).

Is there anyway I can keep the data within both these elements? 
(If needed I can change the names of these two elements if something more semantic is required)

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see language nor copyright in the source of your pipe (the one you get with **Fetch Feed**). But in any case, yes, I'm afraid Yahoo Pipes will remove non-standard fields from its RSS output. Your only option might be embedding those tags in the content (description) of the items.

Comment: Hi @janos thanks for your comment and I've seen other posts you've made on Pipes that have been helpful.

I guess my only alternative if I am stick with Pipes is to output in a format other than RSS that will allow custom elements. Pephaps an xml feed? I can't find any documentation on this. Have you any tips?

Thanks again.

Comment: Either use a different output (JSON), or insert your custom tags in the description element when you generate your RSS. I don't see another way.

Answer (score 0):

As @janos said, your two viable options are to:

1. Get the output as json, which preserves all the elements
2. Concatenate the results into the description field of the RSS.  Create a loop box, put string builder into the loop, and add all the fields you want into it, then assign it to item.description

Or another idea: filter your feed by language.  You could have user input for a language field, and then create a feed that was all english articles, all arabic, whatever you want.